# Analyze Run time of nested for loop

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm having some issues determining if this nested for loop runs in O(n) or O(n^2).

Suppose I have a list of performances P and each performance has a duration (# of hours).

```
P = [P1, P2, ...., Pn]
for p in P:
    for hour in p.hours:
        //do stuff here
    end
end
```

What would be considered the running time of this? I know the total number of executions would be the sum of all the hours in each performance or O(totalHours) but is this linear or polynomial? Keep in mind the # of hours can vary from performance to performance and can be arbitrarily large or small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably say it's `O(mn)`, where `n` is the number of performances and `m` is the average number of hours per performance (or, as you say, `O(totalHours)`).

It's linear in the total number of hours.

Since it's not only dependent on the number of performances, I don't believe you can say it's linear (or even polynomial, for that matter) in that (even though the power of `n` is `1` in the above complexity) (but opinions may vary here).

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So since it would be `O(mn)`, that is still upper bounded by `O(cn^2)` right? Actually `m` is independent from `n` so I'm not sure.

Comment: @1337holiday If there is no upper bound to the number of hours of any given performance, `m` can be greater than any function of only `n`, thus we need to write the complexity in terms of both `n` and `m`.

Answer (score 1):

It's linear on the total number of hours in the input. If that number cannot be expressed as a function of the number of performances then you can't link the running time to the number of performances.

Comment: @1337holiday: "Linear" means "polynomial of degree one". So yes.